# Distinguish between Flux takeUntil condition or upstream complete

Tags: java, project-reactor

How can I determine what caused my `Flux` to complete?

Imagine this example stream:

```
    Flux.range(1, 10)
        .log()
        .takeUntil(i -> i == 5)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
```

Will log `1,2,3,4,5` and terminate.

However, if we change the source stream to terminate early:

```
    Flux.range(1, 3)
        .log()
        .takeUntil(i -> i == 5)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
```

It will log `1,2,3` and also terminate.

I'd like to throw an error whenever the source stream completes before the `takeUntil` condition is met. What is the best way to achieve this using Reactor?

Putting a `doOnComplete` before the `takeUntil` will work, but this feels flaky and error prone. I can imagine this breaks depending on the source's prefetch.

```
    Flux.range(1, 3)
        .log()
        .doOnComplete(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
        .takeUntil(i -> i == 5)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a pretty acceptable way to go, but indeed, it has some corner cases. While it should not break on prefetch, it may be broken if downstream code applies operators such as `.take(2)`. In such cases, the `cancel` signal will be promoted to upstream operators, and your code will not throw an exception even if the required condition is not met.

Another way is to manually track the condition and check it on `complete` and `cancel` signals. (or even on `error` depending on your needs). It is not so elegant but more reliable.

p.s. sorry for kotlin kode, but it's close to java so I think you understand the idea.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val sourceFlux = Flux.range(1, 3)
        .log()
    ConditionalFlux(sourceFlux)
        .takeUntil { it == 5 }
        .doOnNext { println("hello $it") }
        .doOnError { println("condition was not meet") }
        .blockLast()
}

class ConditionalFlux<T : Any>(
    private val origin: Flux<T>
) {
    private val meetCondition = AtomicBoolean()
    private val guardAction = {
        if (!meetCondition.get()) {
            throw RuntimeException()
        }
    }

    fun takeUntil(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Flux<T> =
        origin
            .doOnNext {
                if (predicate(it)) {
                    meetCondition.set(true)
                }
            }
            .doOnCancel { guardAction() }
            .doOnComplete { guardAction() }
            .takeUntil(predicate)
}
```